# Rails 4.2.6 validation takes effect only in console, but not in controller (from browser)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, model

Have gone through several SO rails validation questions, but none is fitting.

My model:

```
class InquiryInteger < Inquiry
    validates :answer, numericality: { only_integer: true, greater_than: 0 }
end
```

Now in the rails console, the validation is working (means: the record is not being saved when instance contains a text:

```
2.3.3 :017 > i1.save
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  Inquiry Exists (0.4ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "inquiries" WHERE ("inquiries"."question_id" IS NULL AND "inquiries"."session_id" = 'jsklkjf8') LIMIT 1
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
 => false
2.3.3 :018 > i1.errors.full_messages
 => ["Answer is not a number"]
2.3.3 :019 > i1.answer
 => "aADDASDASD"
2.3.3 :020 >
```

My controller create-Action:

```
...
respond_to do |format|
  if @inquiry.save
    format.html { redirect_to pages_path(url: params[:url]), notice: 'Thanks for your vote.' }
    format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @inquiry }
  else
    format.html { render action: 'new' }
    format.json { render json: @inquiry.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
...
```

The save method is letting strings through and are stored in the DB. I restarted the thin web server, so changes must have been loaded. Even in byebug, the save method is not showing any messages.

Comment: Is `@inquiry` an `Inquiry` or an `InquiryInteger`?

Comment: it's an InquiryInteger

Comment: How do you create your `InquiryInteger` in the console? How do you do it in the controller?

Comment: You pointed me in the right direction.
In the console, I created the instance correctly: `@inquiry = InquiryInteger.new`.
But in the controllers new action, I first created just the superclass. `@inquiry = Inquiry.new` .
I now set the correct subtype in a case statement in the inquiry's view (e.g. InquiryInteger / InquiryText / etc).
Shall I put the correct solution as an answer here?
Thanks mu-is-too-short

Comment: Yes, I'd recommend putting that down as an answer (and accepting your own answer). `InquiryInteger.new` and `Inquiry.new(type: 'InquiryInteger')` should work fine but `i = Inquiry.new; i.type = 'InquiryInteger'` will be a problem. Also, while I'm hear, you should replace that `validates_numericality_of :answer, presence: true` with `validates :answer, presence: true, numericality: true` as I don't think `validates_numericality_of` understands the `:presence` option; or switch to the `:allow_nil` option.

Comment: I changed the validation accordingly. `validates_numericality_of` seems to be an older helper method name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct subclass has to be set when validating the properties of the instance (obvious).
In the console, I always used `InquiryInteger`, whereas in the controller I missed to set the subtype correctly.

There it was `Inquiry`, thus the validation failed.
After setting the type of the instance correctly ( e.g. `InquiryInteger`or `InquiryText`), the validation finally was effective.